# Is it possible to use the camera while inside Cocas2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I was thinking of using Cocas2D to do some interesting animation stuff and wanted to have that drawn on top of a live preview View from the camera.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, actually.  It is a simple matter of turning the option on in your `GamePlayLayer`:

```
GamePlayLayer* gamePlayLayer = [GamePlayLayer node];
controller = [[CCNodeController controller] retain];

controller.isOverlayingDeviceCamera = YES;
[controller runSceneOnNode: gamePlayLayer];
```

Source: [Cocos2d and UIViewControllers](http://brenwill.com/2010/cocos2d-and-uiviewcontrollers/)